# Service layer = Application layer = GRASP Controller layer

Tags: design-patterns, controller, grasp

I think service/application layer is the same thing as Larman describes as GRASP Controller, being the first object beyond the GUI layer that delegates to the domain layer, and should be reusable from different GUI.

Service (Evans) layer is the same as Application (Fowler) layer because Fowler himself says so, in his "bliki" about the "Anemic Domain Model": http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Quote:
"Application Layer [his name for Service Layer]: Defines the jobs the
software is supposed to do and directs the expressive domain objects
to work out problems. The tasks this layer is responsible for are
meaningful to the business or necessary for interaction with the
application layers of other systems. This layer is kept thin. It does
not contain business rules or knowledge, but only coordinates tasks
and delegates work to collaborations of domain objects in the next
layer down. It does not have state reflecting the business situation,
but it can have state that reflects the progress of a task for the
user or the program."

Now consider the above description (and also see fowler's PEAA book, regarding identifying service layer methods from the use cases) and also consider the picture in Fowler's description of Service layer that illustrates the Service Layer being the first layer after the "user interface" at this URL: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html

Now compare the above mentioned Service/Application layer description
with some of Larman's words about the GRASP Controller (in the 3rd
edition of his best-selling OOAD book "Aplying UML and patterns", age
302-306) :
"...first object beyond the UI layer that receives and coordinates
("controls") a system operation..."
"...represents a use case scenario within which the system event
occurs..."
"... Normally, a controller should delegate to other objects the work
that needs to be done; it coordinates or controls the activity. It
does not do much work itself...."

I think that Larman's GRASP Controller layer is the same as
Evans/Fowler's Application/Service layer. Do other people disagree ?
Then please explain the significant differences between these concepts, and some example  of Controller class instead of Service/Application class.

My question is born because some say that the creation of model domain objects is the responsibility of the controller, instead of the other service / application layer. But could you give me an example of service layer class and the difference between controller class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there's UI Controller and Domain Controller as most used patterns.

UI Controller coordinates access to View, in an MVC pattern.

Domain Controller coordinates access to Domain, and it's called Service Layer (Fowler, which I prefer) or Application Layer (Evans).

Both are indirection layers (Façade Pattern), used to decouple classes between subsystems/layers. It brings modularity and better maintainability (you can swap domain for remote services or swap view from HTML to Flex, and just change the indirection layer)

GRASP Controller appears to be an hybrid of both. I recommend you to use this term only for analysis, not for implementation.

Hope it helps!

Comment: are these classes conrete by convention? I kinda like to store state on them IMHO, I find it more simpler...

Comment: @Wanderson Santos, imo, there should be no separation of the controllers as UI and Domain. In the MVC, there is no such thing. The controller coordinates the logic done by the (business) services (which in turn handle/transform/process the (domain) model), and the views. Each controller (C), uses (business) services to get the model (M) and provide the view (V) with that model (M). The separation of M-V-C allows you to swap the view technology, not the use of a Facade pattern.

Comment: Facade pattern should be used for services when you notice that multiple (groups of) services are used by multiple clients (client being another service or controller - internal or client being external system).